# ValueError: could not convert string to float from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Why am I getting value error when trying to convert it as float? There are no commas in the numbers.

```
vol
              volume
date    
2012-12-03  4.923456e+07
2012-12-04  5.518025e+08
2012-12-05  6.937129e+07
2012-12-06  6.814400e+07
2012-12-07  6.438596e+07
... ...

2014-04-02  6.344194e+07
2014-05-02  6.544194e+07
```

```
vol.astype(float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: What do you try? to_numeric not working?

Comment: like `vol['volume'] = pd.to_numeric(vol['volume'], errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: vol.astype(float)

Comment: I close again because it seems not check dupe answer, only reaction was `There are no commas in the numbers.` :(